# How can I turn on a looking-at coordinates display?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

In Minecraft: Education Edition, I'm trying to build something for someone; how do I see the coordinates of the block I looking at? I can't turn debug mode on like in Java Edition so is there another way to do it?

Comment: Can you do `/gamerule showcoordinates true`? That might work it might not idk, if it does work ill leave it as an answer

Comment: No like when you turn on debug mode, there is a thing called looking at: x y z @Penguin

Comment: @Coder2195 that is impossible on bedrock/edu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Coord

Looking at a block and opening the chat, then typing `/setblock`  but *don't hit enter!* The autocomplete will show you the x, y, and z.

The more efficient option is to run `/gamerule showcoordinates true` and do some math or stand on the block.

## /fill ?

Let's say you wanna easily `/fill` an area. Stand on one corner, then either remember or write down it's coordinates displayed to you by `/gamerule showcoordinates true`.

Then go to the other corner, look at the block, and type `/fill`  and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> three times. Then just type the earlier set of coords and complete to command.

Comment: is there a way to replicate Looking at Block: x y z

Comment: @Coder2195 are you saying you want to add a debug menu? If so, then you can't (to the extent of my knowledge), sorry!

Comment: :( im building a minecraft mansion for my gf :(((((( @Penguin

Comment: @Coder2195 does this solution work for you then? Also may I ask why you need this? Maybe there's a better way

Comment: I'm trying to make filling easizer so I just look at the block write down coords and then fill location @Penguin

Comment: @Coder2195 I've edited in a easy way to do that, check it out and see if that works

Comment: @Penguin On Java, the easier way with fill is to look at 1 corner, type /fill, hit tab 3 times, then enter. This produces an error (expectably). Now move to the other corner, look at the second block, open chat, hit up arrow to recall the prior (incomplete) command, press tab 3 times and you have the complete set of coords, just add what to fill with. Not sure if bedrock enables this,

Comment: @Coder2195 Seems like a persistent display is not an option, but the `/setblock` approach will produce the coords. Look at given block, type /setblock , press tab 3 times. You should get the coords of the block you're looking at.

Answer (score -1):

You have to go into settings and toggle coordinates. I’m pretty experienced when it comes to Minecraft Edu, and use coordinates quite a bit.

Comment: Can you show those settings? If this was a vanilla setting, I assume someone would have pointed that out already, or is it something that was introduced recently?

Comment: @Joachim He seems to have misunderstood the question, OP wants the coords of the block he is looking at rather than his own position. Also, I don't believe there are mods for Education Edition